# add custom attribute in Admin > sales > order > select order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, adminhtml

i want to custom attribute(publisher) below product name in Admin > sales > order > view
i am talking about this example admin url
yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/194/key/8708c389d84db52a806a3411d367368b/

i am making change in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\items\column\name.phtml
my question is first how to override this core file & how to get custom attribute publisher name below product name
i try this code to get publisher name but not working

```
<div><strong><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Publisher') ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode('<br />', Mage::helper('catalog')->splitpublisher($this->escapeHtml($this->getpublisher()))); ?></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dinesh , Magento do not save `product publisher attribute  and etc  product attribute  in sales_flat_order_item` so you can not get `publisher attribute` value from order item

So need load Magento product Obeject (`Mage::getModel('catalog/product'))` by order item product`($item->getProductId())`  then you can this `attribute value if product is exit in magento`

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
  if($product->getId()){
  /* product is exiting in magento
  $publisher=$product->getPublisher();
  }else{
    /* product has been deleted from  magento  so you can not get product data */

  $publisher='None';
  }
```